# How to Fade In repeater LinkButton using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater, databound

I am pretty new to jquery, I've went over a few examples on W3Schools and then googled my question but didn't find an answer that meets my requirements...

Anyway, I have a repeater that shows linkbuttons horizontally. Needless to say, each time, different amount of such linkbuttons is loaded to the repeater.

Here's the Repeater I'm using:

```
    <div style="position: relative">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repStatuses" 
            onitemdatabound="repStatuses_ItemDataBound" 
            onitemcommand="repStatuses_ItemCommand">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkBtnStatuses" runat="server" CommandName="ShowText" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Priority") + ";" + Eval("LevelID") + ";" + Eval("ID") %>'>
          <div runat="server" id="divSts" class="fontAriel"></div>
        </asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

**I want to create the effect of Fade In using Jquery so that each linbutton will be faded in after the previous had faded in as well**... but I don't know how to combine the jquery code with the RepeaterItem LinkButton.

**Here's the jquery example code I want my application to look like:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#d1").fadeIn(2000);
    $("#d2").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#d3").fadeIn(6000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Demonstrate fadeIn() with different parameters.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes</button>

<br><br>
<div id="d1" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="d2" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="d3" style="width:80px;height:80px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need guidance but any help'd be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long weekend, I've came up with an answer.. It seems that the reason my js / jquery didn't respond was due to the fact that the reference to the `<script src="../../script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` was damaged.

Now here's the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a[id*="repStatuses"]').each(function () {
        $(this).show(2500);
        $(this).delay(1000);
    });
});
```

I refer to `a` here because the LinkButton is rendered to an `<a>` element.

Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a javascript loop with sleep:

```
var numberofbuttonsToDisplay = 5;

for (i=1;i<=numberofbuttonsToDisplay;i++)
{
  $('#d'+i).fadeIn(1000);
  sleep(1000);
}
```

It would wait 1 second before displaying the next button while fading in the actual button.

Comment: Your answer is a great solution but I think you didn't quiet get me, I don't have those divs, instead all I have is `<asp:LinkButton>` in a `Repeater`. And I am looking to approach that linkbuttons individually (or somehow) so that each button will be faded in after the previous one.